# Changing only the color of only the Tapped Frame

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im using a method to change the color of my Frame that is inside a ListView with Bindings and when the Frame is Tapped I want to change only the color of that Frame and it's changing the color of all my others frames.

My xaml code:

```
<Frame>
...

<telerikDataControls:RadListView x:Name="sizesListView" Margin="2,0,2,2">
                            <telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                                        <listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                                            <Frame Padding="0" CornerRadius="3.5" BackgroundColor="{Binding MainColor, Source={x:Static local:SelectedColor.CurrentColor}}">
                                                    <Grid RowSpacing="0">
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Key}" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        <Label Text="{Binding Path=Value}"  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </Frame>
                                        </listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
                                    </listView:ListViewTemplateCell>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </telerikDataControls:RadListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
                                <listView:ListViewGridLayout SpanCount="3" x:Name="SizeSpanCount" HorizontalItemSpacing="3"/>
                            </telerikDataControls:RadListView.LayoutDefinition>
</telerikDataControls:RadListView>
<Frame.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer 
        Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

My code-behind:

```
public ExtendedButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            selectedBorder = Color.FromHex("#FF8A00");
            defaultBorder = Color.FromHex("#FFFFFF");
            SelectedColor.CurrentColor.MainColor = defaultBorder;
        }

private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _isSelected = !_isSelected;
            var frame = (Frame)sender;

            if (_isSelected)
            {
                SelectedColor.CurrentColor.MainColor = selectedBorder;
            }
            else
            {
                SelectedColor.CurrentColor.MainColor = defaultBorder;
            }
        }

public class SelectedColor : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public static SelectedColor CurrentColor = new SelectedColor();

        private Color _mainColor;

        public Color MainColor
        {
            get { return _mainColor; }
            set
            {
                _mainColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MainColor));
            }
        }

        private Color _backgroundColor;

        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return _backgroundColor; }
            set
            {
                _backgroundColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BackgroundColor));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

I expected this:

[image: I expected this]

I got this:

[image: I got this]

Notice that whenever I select a Frame the other buttons color in other frames change too.

Comment: `var frame = (Frame)sender;` - you get a reference to the tapped Frame and then do nothing with it.  Instead you are changing the value of SelectedColor which is shared by your entire UI.

Comment: @Jason The var frame is the whole button and the frames that I want to change the BackgorundColor are the bottom three buttons (Frames) which are each generated by the ListView. Am I able to associate the var Frame to my frame inside my List View (Bottom three buttons) PS: Since I'm not able to attribute an x:name to the bottom buttons I created the SelectedColor method.

Comment: then I would try binding the colors to a bool Selected property on your model with a ValueConverter.  Update the Selected property on the Model and the colors should update

Comment: @Jason That's not my problem the problem here is that I'm not able to change the three bottom frames in my main Frame, what's happening is that the BackgroundColor is chaning in all main Frames.

Comment: These frames are definitely sharing their binding when they should not. Is there any particular reason you are using a static variable to access your color? If not, I would try removing that.

Answer (score 1):

You are using static binding to set your bottom button's frame: `x:Static local:SelectedColor.CurrentColor`. All of the buttons are using the same property because of the static property. So when you change one though the outside Frame the others changed too.

You can set the parent Frame's binding context to a `SelectedColor` class:

```
<Frame x:Name="ParentFrame">
    <Frame.BindingContext>
        <local:SelectedColor/>
    </Frame.BindingContext>

    ...

    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding MyCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
</Frame>
```

Define a command in that class:

```
public SelectedColor()
{
    MyCommand = new Command(() =>
    {
        // Change the color
        MainColor = Color.Orange;
    });
}
public ICommand MyCommand { set; get; }
```

At last, set the bottom frames' background color's binding source to that parent frame so that you can change it dynamically through the parent frame's command event.

```
<listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
    <Frame Padding = "0" CornerRadius="3.5" BackgroundColor="{Binding BindingContext.MainColor, Source={x:Reference ParentFrame}}">
        ...
    </Frame>
</listView:ListViewTemplateCell.View>
```